# I have brain wave data for different subects aka voltages recorded every X sec. How do I deal with different wave frequency between subjects?

Tags: machine-learning, time-series, data-transformation, wavelet

Brain wave data is really just voltages recorded every certain number of seconds; this becomes a wave with a certain frequency.

I want to use the voltages recorded every, say, 10s in a model; this is essentially time series or sequential data. Problem is every patients' brain waves are recorded in a different frequency. This means that the voltage values in the 10s windows are "stretched" or "squished" depending on the frequency. I need to handle this between/within group variation.

I'm new to dealing with wave type data so not sure if this is obvious question.

Comment: Here is an article on the processing of brain waves that may be a start at https://www.hindawi.com/journals/js/2016/1831742/ ,

Comment: There was a wonderful keynote lecture on analyzing spike train data by Robert Kass at the joint statistical meetings in Baltimore a few years ago.  See https://www.cmu.edu/dietrich/news/news-stories/2017/november/brain-research-underserved-by-statistics.html.